# Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64: "_OBJC_CLASS_$_ADBMobile", symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64 clang: error

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, linker

Doing an Xcode project for an iOS app that integrates an SDK from Adobe Target, which is implemented in a ViewController like so:

```
-(void)welcomeMessageCampaign
{
    [ADBMobile targetClearCookies];

    ADBTargetLocationRequest* locationRequest = [ADBMobile targetCreateRequestWithName:@"welcome-message" defaultContent:@"Find Great Deals Everyday!" parameters:nil];

    [ADBMobile targetLoadRequest:locationRequest callback:^(NSString *content)
     {
         self.welcomeMessage.text = content;
     }];
}
```

The error from the title is as follows, and my team does not know how to fix it:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_ADBMobile", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in ViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: Add the needed framework that includes the `ADBMobile` class.

Comment: I am facing same error for Xcode14 only

Comment: ..as xcode14 remove support of legacy build setting ...

Answer (score 0):

Besides having the Framework.
If your guide is this example.

```
https://github.com/Adobe-Marketing-Cloud/mobile-services/tree/master/samples/iOS/ADBMobileSamples
```

and the problem is in this index

```
ADBMobileSamples/ADBMobileSamples/LocationTargetingController.m
```

The problem is in the valid architectures, check that you do not have x86_64.

It works for me if it looks like this

```
Valid Architectures           arm64 armv7 armv7s
```